# Is selfhosting appropriate for small web projects in both Nancy and ServiceStack?

Tags: linux, mono, servicestack, nancy, self-hosting

Both [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) and [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) have ability to self-hosting. I want to use one of this frameworks to build a web service with Linux and Mono. I am expecting few concurrent connections. Unfortunately Mono has memory leaks in its implementation of ASP.NET, and the only choice for me is "self-hosting". But i am afraid of the small (possibly) potential to keep concurrent connections. Should I rely on their implementation of hosting?

Comment: FYI: ServiceStack v4 is a commercially-supported product and has some limitation...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what memory leaks you're talking about - there are plenty of people using a Mono/Asp.net combination in production, and I'm sure they'd have noticed if it was intrinsically broken.

Either way, I can't talk for ServiceStack, but there's no issue with concurrent connections with the Nancy self host. I'd recommend you put it behind nginx, which will do an excellent job of handling static content, and monitor the service with supervisord.

There's more info on setting that up on our wiki:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-Nancy-with-Nginx-on-Ubuntu

Comment: [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=381), and [few more](https://www.google.com/search?q=mono+asp.net+memory+leaks)

Comment: Well Nancy doesn't run ASP.NET, it just runs an IHttpHandler so things like Session memory leaks etc should not be a concern

Comment: Really? A bug in session support and a Google search? :) Nancy doesn't use ASP.Net sessions, and if you Google IIS Asp.net memory leak you get a bazillion hits too ;)

Comment: @x2bool wasn't suggesting you were rude, just sounds like you're going off half cocked a bit based on bugs that may or may not impact you at all. Self hosting will work fine though I'm sure.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what memory leaks you're referring to either as there are many Mono/ASP.NET sites running in production, e.g. [servicestack.net](http://www.servicestack.net)'s own website runs on Linux and all ASP.NET live demos are running on Nginx/MonoFastCGI.

Anyway like NancyFx, ServiceStack is also a good option, http://razor-console.servicestack.net an example of running a self-hosted website running behind a nginx reverse proxy. Here are some links for running ServiceStack on Mono/Linux:

- [Run ServiceStack as a daemon on Linux](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-ServiceStack-as-a-daemon-on-Linux)
- [Run ServiceStack in Fastcgi hosted on nginx](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-ServiceStack-in-Fastcgi-hosted-on-nginx)
- [Linux-Hosting-Options](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Linux-Hosting-Options)